# Can't set headers after being sent - Node.js redirect issue with a form

Tags: node.js

I have a form that makes a post request to a route. It accepts some input and saves to a database. I then, on successful save, redirect to the original page I was on. My code is below:

```
router.post("/save", function (request, response, next) {
    const metadata = {
        user: currentUser.name + " " + currentUser.surname
        date: <some-val>
    };
form.parse(request, function(err, fields, files){
    if(!fields.name){
        return response.status(400).send({"status": "error", "message": "The name is required" });
    }
    else if(!fields.description){
        return response.status(400).send({"status": "error", "message": "The description is" +
        " required" });
    }
    MediaH.upload(files, metadata, function (error, result) {
        if(error){
            return response.send(error);
        } else {
            Model.save(fields, result, metadata, function (error, result) {
                if(error) {
                    return response.send(error);
                }
                else{
                   return response.redirect("/pages")
                }
            });
        }
    });

});
});
```

The redirect is successful, however if I try and re-upload to my form again, I get a `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.` error. I have no idea where I'm going wrong. I had a look at several similar questions on Stack Overflow and some suggested doing a `return` for the `response.redirect` but it's still not working.

Can anyone help?

**EDIT:**

Put the entire route above.

Comment: Are you sure there is no code after `form.parse` that could be sending something in the response?

Comment: Hi @ExplosionPills, I've made an edit.

Comment: What "next" do? Shouldn't you call it after response.send()? Like
    `response.send(400);
    return next();`